# I want to create already created SharePoint Website on Online SharePoint version

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have already created SharePoint website online. There is no functionality available to create `.aspx` page. My requirement is to create a new `aspx` web page which is using `dll` and process the page. Is it possible to made these changes in online version.

Please let me know the alternate ways to do that task.

Comment: What you mean by no functionality available to create Page? I believe if you have enough permission then you can use `gear` icon which gives option to Add Page, App etc.

Comment: Yes I found that I am able to create .aspx page. Now how to programe it. by adding reference to dll and on click event of page controls.

Comment: Can a web part is possible to use this feature.

Comment: As I said you can't deploy DLL etc.. You should create an APP in that case.. or stick with JavaScript + REST + CSOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Online doesn't support Farm Solutions. Hence you can't deploy a DLL and use Server Side Object Model.

You should change your approach and use either Client Side Object Model or REST.

Or you can use good old SP WebServices.